# Running LinearClassifier.fit with SparseTensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create a LinearClassifer with a sparse binary numpy coo matrix (reports) using a SparseTensor. This is with TensorFlow 0.9.0

I do this as follows:

```
reports_indices = list()
rows,cols = reports.nonzero()
for row,col in zip(rows,cols):
   reports_indices.append([row,col])

x_sparsetensor = tf.SparseTensor(
  indices=reports_indices,
  values=[1] * len(reports_indices),
  shape=[reports.shape[0],reports.shape[1]])
```

The dimensions of reports is 10K by 1.5K.

I then setup the LinearClassifier as follows:

```
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier()

m.fit(x=x_sparsetensor,y=response_vector.todense(),input_fn=None)
```

Response vector is binary and has a length of 10K. This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ddi_prr.py", line 38, in <module>
    m.fit(x=x_sparsetensor,y=response_vector.todense(),input_fn=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 173, in fit
    input_fn, feed_fn = _get_input_fn(x, y, batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 67, in _get_input_fn
    x, y, n_classes=None, batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/data_feeder.py", line 117, in setup_train_data_feeder
    X, y, n_classes, batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, epochs=epochs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/data_feeder.py", line 240, in __init__
    batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/data_feeder.py", line 44, in _get_in_out_shape
    x_shape = list(x_shape[1:]) if len(x_shape) > 1 else [1]
TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()
```

Is my construction incorrect for some reason? It seems that LinearClassifier.fit can't be instantiated with a SparseTensor for x, is that true? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, passing `SparseTensors` as `x` or `y` arguments to `.fit` is [not supported](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#LinearClassifier):

> x: matrix or tensor of shape [n_samples, n_features...]. Can be
>   iterator that returns arrays of features. The training input samples
>   for fitting the model. If set, input_fn must be None.

Also, `SparseTensor` is a sparse equivalent of `Tensor` -- an object representing symbolic computation to be executed. I believe what you would like to use as `x` is [SparseTensorValue](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#SparseTensorValue).
You can try pass it using other way of passing data to Estimator: `input_fn` function:

```
def get_input_fn(sparse_x, y):
  def input_fn():
    return sparse_x, y
m.fit(input_fn=get_input_fn(x, y))
```

if it won't work, you may try to produce the `SparseTensor`s inside the `input_fn` function.